# Android development & hardware testing - Which handsets & tests? What are the best options/deals?

Tags: testing, android, hardware

I'm quite new to Android development. I spent a few weeks, doing tutorials and developping simple apps.

Now, I'm focusing on all the test aspects. I have done Junit tests before so I thought it would be OK but now I'm slightly worried about the test coverage required.

First, how to test with hardware with that many different devices?? I though I would just buy one but now I'm not so sure.

There are so many handsets and they are so different! hardware feature missing, different resolutions, different lib version, etc

Have you guys got statistics about which handset sell the best per country? So that we can just buy the 2,3 most representative phones? Is there any developer deals where you buy 3 phones + 1 contract for a reasonable price (I'm in the UK btw).

Also, to go back to emulator tests, is there a way to kind of convert a famous handset into the corresponding AVD? Is there some nice free test infrastructure available that make multi-AVDs, multi-config, multi-projects test easier? Now I know most of the programs such as adb,android,emulator, etc... Still will probably need to write some python scripts which integrate them all..

Anyway, I'm slightly puzzled here so any pointer, any comment about your own android test strategy would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Mikael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good [blog-post](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/) on creating AVDs which mimic some popular devices (at the time!). Unfortunately you still have to do these by hand :-( Maybe if you dig up some more recent models you can use this blog-post to create some up-to-date AVDs

v2.2 is still the most popular (see [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)) and if you target v2.1 you should have covered more than 90% of what's installed out there. In my view, if you test on 1 or 2 real devices and a couple more AVDs you're *good-to-go* to deploy it on the Android Market. If your app crashes you (can) get a crash report from the user, which will give you more insight on a per device installation in the real world.

Good luck!

Johan

Comment: 2 great links, cheers!